# Switching between two colors on a awesome wm container widget

Tags: colors, lua, widget, awesome-wm

I create a `wibox.container.background` with something like:

```lua
local w = wibox.widget({
        {
          id = "texte",
          text = "mon texte",
          widget = wibox.widget.textbox
       },
       bg = beautiful.bg_normal,
       widget = wibox.container.background
})
```

Now I want to switch between two background colors with:

```lua
w.bg = w.bg == beautiful.bg_normal and beautiful.bg_focus or beautiful.bg_normal
```

But that doesn't work. It seems `w.bg` refers to a solid pattern and not to a simple hexa color string.

Am I pointing to the correct `bg` variable?

Comment: can you `print(w.bg)` and `print(beautiful.bg_normal)` please?

Comment: `w.bg` contains `lgi.rec 0x558457e4d920:cairo.SolidPattern` and `beautiful.bg_normal` contains "#000000"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you keep your own variable `local is_focus = true` and use that to update the background.

What happens is that the background "string" that you specify goes through `gears.color` and is transformed into a cairo pattern. That is what is then actually used for drawing. You could also pass in a cairo pattern directly and avoid the "loop" through `gears.color`.

Example for my proposed solution:

```lua
local w = wibox.widget({
        {
          id = "texte",
          text = "mon texte",
          widget = wibox.widget.textbox
       },
       bg = beautiful.bg_normal,
       widget = wibox.container.background
})
local is_focused = false
local function switch_background()
    is_focused = not is_focused
    w.bg = is_focused and beautiful.bg_focus or beautiful.bg_normal
end
```